# RX channel out of range for configured RX frontends

Tags: c++, gnuradio, uhd

I have a simple c++ test program on a Ettus x310 that used to work now doesn't.  I'm trying to simply set two center freq of two channels of a single USRP.  The above Out of range error occurs when I try to set anything on the 2nd channel.

I get a crash with a Channel out of range error:

```
    $ ./t2j.out
    linux; GNU C++ version 4.8.4; Boost_105400; UHD_003.009.001-0-gf7a15853

    -- X300 initialization sequence...
    -- Determining maximum frame size... 1472 bytes.
    -- Setup basic communication...
    -- Loading values from EEPROM...
    -- Setup RF frontend clocking...
    -- Radio 1x clock:200
    -- Initialize Radio0 control...
    -- Performing register loopback test... pass
    -- Initialize Radio1 control...
    -- Performing register loopback test... pass
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'uhd::index_error'
      what():  LookupError: IndexError: multi_usrp: RX channel 140445275195320 out of range for configured RX frontends
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my test program:

```
int main( void )
{
// sources
gr::uhd::usrp_source::sptr  usrp1;

const std::string           usrp_addr = std::string( "addr=192.168.10.30" );
uhd::stream_args_t          usrp_args = uhd::stream_args_t( "fc32" );
usrp_args.channels = std::vector<size_t> ( 0, 1 );
usrp1 = gr::uhd::usrp_source::make( usrp_addr, usrp_args );
usrp1->set_subdev_spec( std::string( "A:AB B:AB" ), 0 );
usrp1->set_clock_source( "external" );
usrp1->set_samp_rate( 5.0e6 );

usrp1->set_center_freq( 70e6, 0 );    // this is OK
usrp1->set_center_freq( 70e6, 1 );   // crashes here With RX Chan out of Range Error!

printf( "test Done!\n" );

return 0;
}
```

The only thing Ive found so far in searching is make sure PYTHONPATH is set correctly (and for the heck of it I made sure it pointed to the site_packages) but again that seems to be related to GRC and not C++.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 and UHD 3.9.1 with gnuradio 3.7.8.1 (Ive also tried 3.7.9.2) with the same result.

The hardware is an Ettus x310 with two BasicRx daughterboards.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the gnuradio/uhd Mailing List helped me.  It appears that the vector initialization was wrong:

Replace:
    stream_args.channels = std::vector ( 0, 1 );
With these two lines:
    stream_args.channels.push_back( 0 );
    stream_args.channels.push_back( 1 );

There are other more concise methods but this does the trick for now.

-Bob